# Maximum number of subgraphs of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Can any body tell me that how many maximum subgraphs of a graph can possibly be there.
it would be good if you can give me some explanation of the answer that how one can calculate that.
Thanks

Comment: May I ask how this is related to algorithms? It's just a bit of math

Comment: @harold I disagree, there is probably a recursive algorithm here :)

Comment: @nicolaskruchten well I disagree with the disagreement, the way the OP stated it he's looking for the number of valid subgraphs of the complete graph (because that number would be maximum compared to all other graphs with equally many nodes) and there's no algorithm there.

Comment: @harold I would like to know what procedure and/or formula could simultaneously answer the question and not count as an 'algorithm' in your view :)

Comment: @nicolaskruchten any formula, formula's aren't algorithms, they are more abstract than that and don't define how to evaluate them.

Comment: I think this belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like homework, so here's a few hints: The definition of a subgraph is that it consists of a subset of the nodes of the graph, and of a subset of those edges from the original graph that go between the selected nodes. (Edit: My original reply was erroneous, as "a subset of" was missing.) <strike>In other words, the question "how many subgraphs are there" has the same answer as "in how many ways can we pick subsets of the nodes", which is essentially the same question as "given a set *V*, how many subsets of *V* are there"?</strike> Edit: Thus, as @andrew cooke points out, although it is simple to express how many possible node subsets there are, the number of possible edge subsets for each node subset depends on the structure of the graph, so there is no simple formula for this.

Comment: The set of all subgraphs isn't just the set of all subsets of nodes and edges... Consider the graph `A-B-C-D`: Nodes A and B and edge CD doesn't comprise a subgraph. Neither is it the set of all subsets of edges-and-associated-nodes, as `A-B C-D` isn't a subgraph either.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten: he didn't say that any of those are subgraphs. what are you talking about?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten: Your observations are correct, but as yi_H says, that's not what I said. I said to pick a subset of the _nodes_ and then pick _all_ edges where both edge endpoints are in the selected subset.

Comment: OK fair enough I misread that. I still think there's a problem with this answer in that if you have, for example, a fully-connected graph of 5 nodes, there exist subgraphs which contain 4 of those nodes and yet don't contain all of the edges connected to all of those 4 nodes. Or for that matter all 5 nodes with only a subset of the edges. This is a combinatorics problem, just not a straightforward one.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten: That _is_ indeed an error on my part. I've corrected it; thanks.

Comment: your connection still isn't correct since you're implying (i think) that the sub-graph is defined completely by the set of nodes.  but you can also (as nicoalskrutchen said) select different subsets of edges.  this also means that there is no simple combinatorics (is that a word?  no simple arithmetic expression involving the size of the graph) answer (unless you're considering, say, all complete subgraphs of a complete graph)

Comment: @andrew cooke: Gah; I'm apparently not quite awake today - you are entirely correct. Edited the answer again (to now become pretty much useless...)

Answer (score 0):

let the number of edges be E and no. of vertices be V.
number of subgraphs:
2^V + C(E,1)*2^(V-2) + C(E,2)*2^(Vertices left) + .... go on until all the edges are covered.